# How can I add more than one custom property to an object?

Tags: properties

When I press ADD, the same property appears duplicated and I cannot see the properties list.

I am working in a plane design for Real Flight Simulator 8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when clicking on ADD, a new line appears with the property default name prop, which you can change for the required value.